# Odoo / insert sale line without reloading page

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

In Odoo I want to add a function to insert a sale-line between other lines.
I've done this with:

*in view:*

```
<button name="add_line" type="object" string="+" icon="fa-add" class="oe_edit_only"/>
```

*in model:*

```
def add_line(self):
    for rec in self:
        new_sequence = rec.sequence + 1
        # create new orderline
        new_sale_line = self.env['sale.order.line'].create({ 
                "order_id": rec.order_id and rec.order_id.id or False,
                "sequence": new_sequence,
                #supply default values
                "product_id" : rec.product_id and rec.product_id.id or False,
                "product_uom" : rec.product_uom and rec.product_uom.id or False,
                "customer_lead" : 0,
                "name" : "",
                "price_unit" : 0,
                "product_uom_qty" : 1
            })
        # update sequence of following orderlines
        for line in rec.order_id.order_line:
            if line.xaa_nif_regel_nr > new_sale_line.xaa_nif_regel_nr and line.sequence >= new_sale_line.sequence:
                line.sequence = line.sequence + 1
```

This basically works. But when I've a large order, and click my add-button, the page does a reload. And also this method requires setting a product on the inserted line, while we in fact want to have a new blank line.)

What I want to achieve is the reverse effect for what the `delete`-button does: this removes the line, and stays on active scroll-position.
Now I want to insert a line, and let browser stay on active scroll-position.

Comment: Have you try self._cr.execute command in order to create SO line(s) instead of using ORM? { self._cr.execute("""INSERT INTO sale_order_line .........) }

Comment: No I didn't. I can't imagine this will solve the whole issue, because this needs hard database-call, and I'm looking for an in-memory-method (like 'adding new line at bottom').